# How many integral ordered pairs satisfy this equation

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $n, x, y$ are positive integers

How many ordered pairs (x, y) are there with $\dfrac{xy}{x+y} = n$

Comment: If $x=y$ is allowed, set $x=y=2\alpha, \alpha \in \Bbb Z$ and then $n<\alpha$ and you've got infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{xy}{x+y}=n\\\Rightarrow xy=n(x+y)\\\Rightarrow xy-n(x+y)=0$$

As an attempt to factorise, and noting symmetry, we add $\pm\ n^2$ to the LHS, which gives

$$xy-n(x+y)+n^2=n^2\\\Rightarrow (x-n)(y-n)=n^2$$

All we need to do now is count the number of such pairs. But this is simply $$2\tau(n^2),$$

since we are counting integral pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Taking reciprocals,
$$ \frac1x+\frac1y=\frac 1n$$
from which we see that necessarily $x,y>n$.
So write $x=n+u$, $y=n+v$.
Transform the original equation  to 
$$ xy=n(x+y)$$
Now substituting gives
$$ (n+u)(n+v)=n(2n+u+v).$$
Expand this and arrive at a surprising simple equation that helps us relate the number of solutions with the number of positive divisors of $n^2$.